# Default Project Site Templates missing in Enterprise Project Type (Project Server 2016)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, project-server, project-templates

I'm working on Project Server 2016.

We had created the site collection backup from a Production environment and restored on UAT environment. The restoration was successful.

However, when I checked the "Enterprise Project Type", I cannot find the default Project Site Templates.

UAT Screenshot:

[image]

Production Screenshot:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just disable the pwa site feature and then enable it as shown below:

```
Disable-SPFeature pwasite -URL SiteCollectionURL

Enable-SPFeature pwasite -URL SiteCollectionURL
```